# Using bootstrap-switch with Rails' check_box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, erb

I need to display a checkbox for a User's field. Currently I do so using:

```
<%= f.label :is_name_public, "Public name" %>
<%= f.check_box :is_name_public %>
```

Now I want to use [bootstrap-switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) with Rails' chech_box. In order to use the switch button, the checkbox needs to be something like:

`<input id="user_is_name_public" name="user[is_name_public]" type="checkbox" value="1"  data-size="small" data-on-color="success" data-on-text="Yes" data-off-text="No">`

instead of Rails' default:

`<input id="user_is_name_public" name="user[is_name_public]" type="checkbox" value="1">`

The **question is**, how to tell Rails to add custom properties like `data-size="small"` or `data-on-color="success"` to the checkbox? Or how to associate a custom html checkbox with the entity being edited by the form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add more attributes to the default ones:

```
<%= f.check_box :is_name_public, :class => 'someclass' %>
```

The same is true for the data attribute:

```
<%= f.check_box :is_name_public, :data => { :size => 'small', 'on-color'=>'success'} %>
```

Notice how the `:data => { :size => 'small' …` bit will be transformed into `data-size="small"` in the resulting HTML.

Comment: Since I wasn't adding a class, I had to use the second code snippet. It worked perfectly!

Comment: thank you. I used this to change the text as well `'on-text'=>'Yes', 'off-text'=>'No'`